# Create archive and add all files from a specific path that match a certain type

Tags: php, linux, tar

I want to create an archive and add all file from a given path that match a certain type.

I tried something like this:

```
system("tar -czvf /home/site/public_html/archive.tar.gz `find . -type f -name '.sql'`");
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, i've found a proper command:

```
system("cd /home/site/public_html/ && tar -czvf /home/site/public_html/archive.tar.gz *.sql");
```

Using cd we change the directory were we operate then we create an archive using tar in a certain path and look for the files matching the .sql pattern in the current folder to add them in the archive

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is wrong, try this command instead :

```
system("tar -czvf /home/site/public_html/archive.tar.gz `find . -type f -name '*.sql'`");
```

**EDIT :**

Since my first solution doesn't work, try this now :

`system("find . -name '*.sql' | tar -cvzf /home/site/public_html/archive.tar.gz --files-from -");`

Comment: Use $(..) instead of legacy  `  ` for `bash` command substitution. Proper usage would be `tar -czvf /home/site/public_html/archive.tar.gz "$(find . -type f -name '*.sql')"`

Comment: this is the command system("tar -czvf $bkp_db_targz $(find . -type f -name '*.sql')");